# Get the precise x/y position of guides for precisely aligning shapes to them using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is there any way to get the precise - as in including decimal places -  x/y position of a guideline using VBA?

When getting the position of a guides in PPT via VBA, the result is not as precise as required. Decimal places are omitted. This is confusing me, since the variable type is "Single" which should incorporate decimal places.

The overarching goal is to "snap" shapes of all kinds to guides using VBA. Use case: User selects one or multiple shapes and wants to align them all to the leftmost guide in the presentation by just clicking a button.

My code works fine thus far, the only issue being that the shapes don't get precisely aligned with the guides.

```vb
Sub align_left()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim gd As Guide
    With ActiveWindow.Selection
        On Error Resume Next
        x_gd = ActiveWindow.Width

        MsgBox x_gd

        For Each gd In ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Guides
            If gd.Orientation = ppVerticalGuide And gd.Position < x_gd Then
                x_gd = gd.Position
            End If
        Next

        MsgBox x_gd

        For Each shp In .ShapeRange
            shp.Left = x_gd
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Expected: Shapes "snap" to guides.
Actual: Shapes are moved CLOSE to the guides but depending on guide position, there's still a gap between guides and shapes.

Comment: I guess, you found a rounding bug. Hint: `Application.Width` and `ActiveWindow.Width` are larger than a slide. You should use `ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Width` or `ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth` for the first comparison.

Comment: Is there any work-around for this bug? I tried `CDbl(gd.Position)` but it still returns a rounded number without decimal places. Setting the position of a guide works precisely though. For example, adding two guides at e.g. 25.1 and 25.3 clearly works with double-level precision as they are placed visibly apart.

Comment: The only workaround springing to mind is to move all their positions to a rounded value first, e. g. `gd.position = gd.position`.

Comment: Too bad - that pretty much kills the use case for me. Thanks for your help, though! I can't think of a different way to move all selected shapes to the left-most guide of the corporate design-compliant slidemaster.

Comment: Completely different workaround: If just *one* other shape is already at the correct position (and can be identified by its size, color, tags, alternativetext, whatever), how about using its `Left` coordinate for positioning all your desired shapes?

Comment: That would work indeed. However, the macro should work explicitly in cases, where there's no such shape present. Guess I'll just have to live with the fact that this macro is not possible as of now. Thank you anyhow, Asger.

Answer (score 1):

I would say to round to 4 decimals, as dimensions are set as Single values

```
            shp.Left = Round(x_gd, 4)
            shp.Top = Round(y_gd, 4)
```

Comment: The value returned when you query the position of a guide is rounded to 0 decimal positions, so rounding it again won't help.

Comment: @Steve I tried ```ReDim gd As Single``` but it was marked as Syntax Error. Would there be a way to avoid the rounding? Else, I was thinking that placing the guides on the grids could be a less problematic solution.

Comment: ReDim is used to resize arrays; it can't be used to change the type of a variable mid-stream. Putting the guides on the grid would work, so long as the grid spacing is set such that the grid falls on even numbers; forcing the guild positions to be pre-rounded, so to speak.